# R: object not found when knitting

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to run build a `knn` model using `caret` with my dataset where `True` (real sales), `DOW` (Day of the week), and `D1` to `D10` (historic sales) are available.

```
library(caret)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(dummies)

#data
rm = matrix(rnorm(100*10, 10, 5), nrow = 100) %>% as.data.frame()
wide = cbind(
  rnorm(100, 100, 1),
  weekdays(seq(as.Date('2019/1/1'), by='day', length.out = 100)),
  rm
)
colnames(wide) = c('true', 'DOW', paste0('D',1:10))

#preprocessing for knn
train.true = train[,1] 
dow.tr = dummy(train$DOW, sep='.')
dow.te = dummy(test$DOW, sep='.')
k.train = cbind(train[, -c(2, nearZeroVar(train))], dow.tr)
k.test = cbind(test, dow.te)[,-2]

seq.knn.pre1 = rep(0, nrow(test))
for (i in 1:10){
  this.train = k.train[, c((i+1):ncol(k.train))]
  this.test = k.test[i, c((i+1):ncol(k.test))]
  train.control = trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=10, repeats = 1)

  k = train(train.true~., method='knn', tuneLength = 8, 
            trControl=train.control, preProcess='scale',
            data=data.frame(train.true, this.train))
  seq.knn.pre1[i] = predict(k, this.test)
}
seq.knn.pre1 = cbind(true = test[,1], k.pred1 = seq.knn.pre1) %>% data.frame()
```

However, when I am knitting the file, it gives me `error` `object 'X.Rachel.Documents.Research.file.Rmd.Friday' not found Calls: <Anonymous> ... predict.train -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval Execution halted`.

---

I am guessing the problem might come from the DOW dummy variables. When my simulated dataset does not include categorical variables, the code knitted well. Is there any possibility that I can fix it there?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't look like an R markdown file, I'm not sure I understand how you are knitting it. Also, did you change part of the error message or is "xxx" literally part of the message? I can't quite tell exactly what's happening here.

Comment: I did, the "xxx" part is the path of this file I am knitting into and my filename. I updated the original error message.

Comment: If you're using RStudio and all your files are in the project directory, maybe selecting Knit > Knit Directory > Project Directory will help.

Comment: The error message references an object "X.Rachel.Documents.Research.file.Rmd.Friday". What is that? It seems to be in a part of your code that you haven't included here. I'm guessing that 1. you may have forgotten quotation marks somewhere, making this seem like an object instead of a string with a file name, and 2. you don't actually want "Friday" to be a file extension

Comment: @camille You're correct! I missed the quotations around the object. Sorry about the confusions. The file name is just "file" and I am guessing "Friday" is part of the variable and I have no idea why it is there.